# Why do aliyos end with a different tune?

Tags: torah-reading, trop-cantillation

The communal Torah reading is divided into *aliyos*, sections read (originally and still in some places by, otherwise) on 'behalf' of distinct people, in succession. The Torah is read in a tune, and each verse ends with the same tune — except that, in most synagogues I've been in, the final verse of each *aliya* ends with a different tune than other verses do. Why the change?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably this is a cue to the *oleh* that the aliyah is over, and he should begin reciting the blessing. If the *kore* were to simply stop reading, there would be a few seconds of awkward silence until the *oleh* is sure that the aliyah is over. Also, a *kore* who pauses for whatever reason would run the risk of having the *oleh* start the blessing too early.

Comment: Not sure why it would be so bad if an oleh started early. Aliyot breaks are _very_ flexible.

Comment: @DoubleAA - That wouldn't be a disaster, but it makes sense that a *kore* would want things to go the way he planned and practiced.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, they're flexible, but there are places where this could cause confusion as to the appropriate place to begin the following aliyah. Not to mention that ending an aliyah too early can sometimes be halachically problematic, especially during weekday readings with short aliyos.

Comment: So according to this answer, this wouldn't have applied before they started using a designated _kore_.