# Are the conventional chapter divisions of any entire books of Tanach originally from Jewish tradition?

Tags: tanach, tehilim-psalms, megillat-esther, mesorah-tradition, lamentations-eicha

In general, the conventional division of the books of Tanach into chapters is [not based on Jewish tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15446/why-doesnt-the-second-chapter-of-breishit-begin-at-24) but on Christian invention. However, there are some books of Tanach in which various practices that I've seen seem to take the conventional chapter divisions into account, such as:

- Reading a Psalm (i.e. chapter of Tehillim) as a unit, either as part of formal liturgy or as informal prayer.
- In public readings of all five [Megillot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Megillot), singing a concluding flourish at the ends of chapters.

Are the conventional chapter breaks in Tehillim, any of the Megillot, or any other complete book of Tanach entirely consistent with a Jewish tradition for breaking up that book?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36805/4940

Comment: Some old editions of Eikha have four chapters (the latter two are put together) FWIW. It's clear the 5 chapters of Eikha are distinct units. Is that enough? What do you need to prove that those are "Jewish stops"?

Comment: Some editions of Tehillim have 147 chapters http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4684/759  . Does this answer the question, or are you wondering if the 150 is a Jewish tradition too, even if not universal?

Comment: @DoubleAA A write-up of that whole issue (along the lines of Tehillim: according to some, yes; according to some, almost, ...) would be constitute great answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA Do you have a reference for 4-chapter Eikha?

Comment: I believe the chapter divisions come from when Christian printers were in charge of printing Jewish seferim

Comment: @EzraHoerster that information is part of the basis for this question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - that's why it's a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: There are cases in which the christians who invented the chapter numbers happened to get it right. Many times they did not.

Comment: No sources, but I believe Eichah and Tehillim were originally divided into five and 150 perakim respectively.

Comment: @magicker72 Try https://archive.org/stream/The_Second_Rabbinic_Bible_Vol_1/1#page/n9/mode/2up on page 10, though later in volume 4 he does print a 5th chapter heading. Maybe he changed his mind?

Answer (score 2):

The book of Obadiah has one chapter. I haven't seen anyone break it into multiple chapters.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP was counting Trei Asar as 12 or 1 unit(s). He should clarify.